# C++ Replace/Update Binary line in .dat file

Tags: c++, binary, fwrite

I know this code is not the most appropriate to use (I'm just really new to C++, and tight on time)

I need to update a line in a binary file. I've got the `int i` value, which is the line number I'm supposed to change.

This is the structure:

```
typedef struct {
    string nome;
    string morada;
    string codpostal;
    string localidade;
    int telefone;
    int nContribuinte;
} CLIENTE;
```

This is saved into `PSI.dat` with `fwrite(&Clt, sizeof(Clt), 1, f);` where `Clt` is `CLIENTE Clt`. There way I'm getting the line to update is as follows:

`Clt` has already been filled with the updated information by the user.

`i` is obtained by `while (infile >> line) { if (line == n) { break; }i++; }` where `n` is a user input to get where information is

```
    fwrite(&Clt, sizeof(Clt), 1, f); // Instead of writing, this should replace line 'i' from PSI.dat

    fclose(f);
```

I'll need code example to get me going, cause I'm really stuck on this part.

Comment: I've corrected myself, wrong choice of words :) C++ Windows Console Project

Comment: if `string` above is a C++ `std::string` then this is undefined behavior